# Permisos de ejecución de shell con vala

Tags: linux, shell, gtk, vala

Estoy actualmente desarrollando un proyecto en `vala` que necesita de `ui` forzosamente para iniciar o detener un servicio especifico (por ejemplo apache2), utilicé `Posix` para la ejecución de los comandos como `sudo service apache2 stop` pero no encuentro como hacer que tenga permisos de superusuario para que realice este tipo de ejecución.
Al ejecutarlo me da este error:

```
** (main:7465): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: permission denied.
```

Aqui el código:

```
using Gtk;
using Posix;

public class App : Gtk.Application {

    public App () {
        Object (application_id: "com.github.iuninefrendor.command",
        flags: ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE);
    }

    protected override void activate () {
        var window = new Gtk.ApplicationWindow (this);
        window.title = "Comandos";
        window.set_default_size (1024, 768);
        
        Box box= new Box (Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 0);
        
        Button iniciar = new Button.with_label ("Iniciar Apache");
        iniciar.clicked.connect (() => {
            Posix.system("sudo service apache2 restart"); //error al usar sudo, necesario
        });
        
        Button detener = new Button.with_label ("Detener Apache");
        detener.clicked.connect (() => {
            Posix.system("sudo service apache2 stop"); //error al usar sudo, necesario
        });
        
        box.pack_start (iniciar, false, false, 10);
        box.pack_start (detener, false, false, 10);
        box.margin = 10;
        
        window.add (box);        
        window.show_all ();
    }

    public static int main (string[] args) {
        var app = new App ();
        return app.run (args);
    }
}
```

> Documentación: [Valadoc](https://valadoc.org/)
> Posix: [Posix](https://valadoc.org/posix/index.htm)

#### EDICIÓN 1

El Programa se compila usando `valac` en la terminal generando un ejecutable para distribución:

```
$ valac --pkg posix --pkg gtk+-3.0 app.vala
```

Tambien puede ser generado a código `C` y despues compilado con `gcc`:

```
 $ valac -c --pkg posix --pkg gtk+-3.0 app.vala
 $ gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` app.c -o App `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 posix`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de una larga búsqueda, encontré como forzar los permisos de ejecución como superusuario utilizando un archivo `.policy` ([PolicyKit](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/PolicyKit)) esto de manera gráfica.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
<policyconfig>
  <vendor>iuninefrendor</vendor>
  <action id="polkit.pkexec.iuninefrendor">
    <message gettext-domain="polkit-tutorial">Autenticación es requerida para ejecutar esta aplicación.</message>
    <icon_name>iuni-command</icon_name>
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/iuni-command</annotate>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">true</annotate>
  </action>
</policyconfig>
```

Al momento de instalación (por ejemplo con Cmake, o [generando un .deb](https://antumdeluge.github.io/debreate-web/)) definir esta politica en el siguiente directorio:

```
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/
```

Para que aparezca un dialogo de autenticación, pidiendo credenciales de administrador como el siguiente:

[image: Petición root]

Despues de ello se podrán ejecutar comandos usando la sentencia Posix: `Posix.system("sudo service apache2 stop");` con sudo.

Otra manera es ejecutar el binario correspondiente en la terminal con sudo o agregarlo a la lista sodoers `/etc/sudoers` como menciona @track3r.

> **Un tutorial aqui** (en ingles): [Making a simple Polkit application in Vala and GTK+](https://greyok.github.io/simple-polkit-tutorial.html)
>
> **Una respuesta en AskUbuntu** (en ingles): [How to configure pkexec?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287845/how-to-configure-pkexec)

Answer (score 1):

Puede que el usuario con el que corres el programa, deba autenticarse ya que usas sudo. Deberías probar modificando el fichero /etc/sudoers e intentar que dicho usuario, pueda usar sudo sin tener que escribir la contraseña. En un terminal:

```
sudo visudo
```

Y busca el usuario o añade la siguiente línea:

```
usuario  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Siendo **usuario** el nombre del usuario que ejecuta el programa.

Si no tienes un usuario al uso sino que usas el grupo admin, entonces sería:

```
%admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: El problema es que es un ejecutable para distribución y nunca se sabe cual va a ser el usuario que lo corre, intenté, agregando los permisos al archivo sudoers pero solo funciona en local.

Comment: Entonces debes permitir al usuario que va a correr el programa, que ingrese la contraseña de sudo de su usuario. Como cualquier otro programa que requiere de privilegios para su ejecución.

Comment: Hay otra alternativa si esto no te convence, quitas el sudo e indincas al usuario que el programa requiere privilegios, es decir, tienes 3 opciones en total, preguntas contraseña al usuario, añades el usuario a sudoers o permites al usuario que sepa que requiere privilegios, esto es así por seguridad. Puede que se me escape algo, pero lo veo muy lógico, ¿tu no?

Comment: Gracias, después de tanto buscar encontré una forma de definir los permisos usando PolicyKit de manera gráfica sin afectar la autenticacion de usuarios en sudoers y definirla para ciertas acciones en una aplicación.